# Fedora 13 on 1and1 Dedicated Server

Tags: linux, fedora, 1and1

We currently have a dedicated server with 1and1 which is currently running Fedora core 6 which has old versions of Apache and PHP among others running on it which I don't seem to be able to update using Yum.

I would ideally like to get this up to the latest version of Fedora 13, so my question is there any way to upgrade from 6 to 13 ? I would be happy to wipe the server and start again except 1and1 do not offer Fedora as one of their 'reimaging' options and as I am used to Fedora I would like to stay with this OS (i'm by no means a Linux expert i'm afraid!).

1and1 are saying I could potentially do this through their recovery tool but aren't being any more helpful than this, does anyone know how I could attempt this with 1and1 ?

Thanks in advance!

Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend this. Consider doing a sidegrade to CentOS 4 instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response, they do offer CentOS 5 as one of their standard reimaging options, can I ask why you'd recommend this ?

Comment: Two reasons. The first is that CentOS derives indirectly from Fedora, so you are likely to find it *very* familiar. The second is that the lifecycle for CentOS is 7 years versus Fedora's lifecycle of 13 months, which means far less reinstalling in order to be running a supported version.

Comment: Great stuff, many thanks for the advice, downloading CentOS now so I can play around with it in a virtual machine 1st.